# io.sockets.to(RoomID).emit not woring on nodeJS

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

Code:

```
io.sockets.to(findRoomID).emit('COMPLETE_MATCH', { start: "true" });

 *findRoomID => bbbb
```

Console:

> { bbbb: Room { sockets: { bbbb: true, aaa: true }, length: 2 } }

But the client did not receive `COMPLETE_MATCH` correctly

What should I do??

I uploaded the socket io server code.

Can you tell which part is the problem?

I can not tell which part is the problem.

[Server]

```
const app = require('express');
const http = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(http);

var rooms = [];
var clients = [];

var clients = [];
var rooms = [];

io.on('connection', function(socket) {

    socket.on('MATCH', function (data) {

        socket.leave(socket.id);

        var NickName = data.name;
        socket.id = NickName;
        clients.push(socket.id);

        //search all rooms
        var isEmpty = false;
        var isNum = 0;
        for (var ii = 0; ii < rooms.length; ii++)
        {
            if (rooms[ii].count < 2)
            {
                isEmpty = true;
                isNum = ii;
            }
        }

        if (isEmpty) //join room
        {
            var findRoomID = rooms[isNum].id;
            rooms[isNum].sockets += ',' + socket.id;
            rooms[isNum].count++;
            socket.join(findRoomID);

            //send msg to select room
            io.in(findRoomID).emit('COMPLETE_MATCH', {start: "true"});

        }
        else //create room
        {
            var sockets = {
                id: socket.id,
                sockets : socket.id,
                count: 1
            }
            rooms.push(sockets);
            socket.join(socket.id);

        }

    });

});
```

Client code was written on Unity 5.6.6. Clients can emit `MATCH` correctly but 
 can't get `COMPLETE_MATCH` currectly. 
[Client - Unity5.6.6]

```
public class ScSocket : MonoBehaviour {

    public SocketIOComponent socket;

    public Button btnMatch;
    public InputField input;
    public Text txTest;

    void Start ()
    {
        btnMatch.onClick.AddListener(() => StartCoroutine(StartMatch()));

        //
        socket.On("COMPLETE_MATCH", OnCompletedMatch);

        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
    }

    IEnumerator StartMatch()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);
        Dictionary<string, string> data = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        data.Add("name", input.text);
        socket.Emit("MATCH", new JSONObject(data));
    }

    void OnCompletedMatch(SocketIOEvent evt)
    {
        Debug.Log(evt);
        txTest.text = JsonToString(evt.data.ToString(), "\"");
    }

    string JsonToString(string target, string s)
    {
        string[] newString = Regex.Split(target, s);
        return newString[1];
    }
}
```

Comment: Please put your socket.io complete code and your client code here?

Comment: I uploaded the code. Can you tell which part is the problem??

Comment: You don't have any `Socket.On("COMPLETE_MATCH"` in your client!!!

Comment: Are you emitting `COMPLETE_MATCH` instead of `GAME_START` ?

Comment: oh, My mistake. I brought the code back.

Answer (score 0):

If you want broadcast `COMPLETE_MATCH` to all clients in `findRoomID` expect sender, use:

```
socket.broadcast.to(findRoomID).emit('COMPLETE_MATCH', { start: "true" });
```

but if you want set to all clients in 'findRoomID', use

```
io.in(findRoomID).emit('COMPLETE_MATCH', { start: "true" });
```

In your server code, you are using `socket.id` as room name of connected sockets, but `socket.id` is unique identifier of each connected socket and was generated by socket.io engine. I suggest generate your room name with the random number and dont change `socket.id`

[server]

```
const app = require('express');
const http = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(http);

var clients = [];
var rooms = [];

io.on('connection', function(socket) {

    socket.on('MATCH', function (data) {

        if(socket.roomName){
            socket.leave(socket.roomName);
        }


        socket.NickName = data.name;
        clients.push(socket);

        //search all rooms
        var isEmpty = false;
        var isNum = 0;
        for (var ii = 0; ii < rooms.length; ii++)
        {
            if (rooms[ii].count < 2)
            {
                isEmpty = true;
                isNum = ii;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (isEmpty) //join room
        {
            var findRoomID = rooms[isNum].id;
            rooms[isNum].sockets.push(socket.id);
            rooms[isNum].count++;
            socket.join(findRoomID);

            //send COMPLETE_MATCH to all sockets of this room
            io.in(findRoomID).emit('COMPLETE_MATCH', {start: "true"});

        }
        else //create room
        {
            //generate a random room name
            let roomName = Math.round(Math.random()*(999999999 - 100000000)+ 100000000).toString();

            let room = {id: roomName, sockets:[], count: 0};

            socket.join(roomName);
            socket.roomName = roomName;

            room.sockets.push(socket.id);
            room.count++;

            rooms.push(room);

        }

    });

});
```

Comment: uu.... It does not work. I do not really understand why not. Is there any other way? :)

Comment: I got the wrong code.Can you see the modified code?

Comment: Thank you so much! Your example is the best. :)

Comment: Your welcome, if it's working, set Mark as answer (and up vote if you want) can be helpful for other guys ;)